# How do I get emacs to open in the terminal when it is being used as the config editor?

Tags: configuration, gnome-terminal, emacs, text-editor

I like to use emacs as my configuration editor, so it is the default for programs like `git` or `cron`. So I used

```
sudo update-alternatives --config editor
```

And chose emacs24 from the list.

Unlike Vim or nano, this launches emacs as a new gui application, rather than taking over the current terminal window.

Is there a way to make emacs open in the terminal as a configuration editor, or maybe when it is invoked from the command line, but still allow for launching emacs as a stand-alone application from the launcher or dash?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most utilities, including `git` respect an environment variable named EDITOR which you can set to any editor you want, including options.  `export EDITOR='emacs -nw'` will have them run emacs in non windowed mode.

In the case of `emacs`, it has a handy server mode you can start with `M-x server-start` and then run `emacsclient` as an editor to open a file in the already running emacs instance.  This is handy since it allows you to retain access to the emacs kill ring and other features.  It also accepts the `-nw` switch so that it will open a new emacs frame in the terminal window rather than in the gui emacs frame, so it will still look and feel like a text mode emacs session, but still share the kill ring and buffers with the other window(s).

Answer (score 7):

From @steeldriver comment:

```
git config --global core.editor "emacs -nw"
```

Answer (score 4):

You can invoke emacs with the `-nw` option

```
      -nw, --no-window-system
              Tell Emacs not to create a graphical frame.  If you  use
              this switch when invoking Emacs from an xterm(1) window,
              display is done in that window.
```

Comment: How can I tell programs like `git` to invoke emacs in this way?

Comment: @EricWilson, `export EDITOR='emacs -nw'`.  Personally I prefer to use `emacsclient` so that the file opens in my existing gui emacs window.

Comment: FWIW I think git has its own configurable editor setting as well, e.g. `git config --global core.editor "emacs -nw"`

Comment: @psusi your comment is really the answer to my question (the first sentence). I'd accept it if it were given as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can change this in ~/.gitconfig by adding the following under the section labeled [core]:

```
[core]
        editor = emacs -nw
```